# What is the meaning of these words?

Tags: translation, meaning

I recently watched a celebrity show where an actor said: 我还会演雨戏 我还会演风戏 我不光会演雷剧

What are 雨戏, 风戏, 雷剧?

I guess that these are some kind of television dramas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

雷剧 is short for 雷人电视剧，which means this drama is just one of the worst,making you feel 'shocked'.
雷 also means thunder in Chinese.So 雨戏 and 风戏 actually mean nothing, the actress was just playing with language.

Comment: Agree. It's kind of wordplay, which has some funny effect though.